# Is it okay to put a short hint as a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, scope

Writing an answer as a comment at Stack Exchange is considered as troublesome, but *sometimes* it is not possible to write an immediate answer (due to lack of time/ knowledge), but it seems useful if the asker can get some useful information when the asker is waiting. Sometimes established users do that ([such as this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/53762/does-body-compensate-for-t-cell-death-caused-by-hiv#comment94458_53762)). As well, a user expressed their view [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2653/why-are-answers-being-posted-in-the-comments-on-the-question/2654#2654) that they includes short hints as comments. According to that answer;

> There are at least two reasons why I sometimes post answers as comments...
>
> 1. I voted to close the question. Perhaps I consider it "off-topic", so I don't want to see multiple answers being voted on. But if I think I know the answer and can easily express it in a comment, I often do this.
> 2. **I don't have the time/inclination/knowledge to provide a full answer, so I put down something in a brief comment, hoping someone else will pick up the ball and run with it.**

However, a few times I've seen that quick hint or quick, yet incomplete   information, as a comment on Stack Exchange, being considered as "answer as comment" (here is [one recent example](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/53794/why-is-glycine-considered-a-nonpolar-amino-acid-but-a-polar-molecule/54128#comment94464_53794)).

However, I don't know if is there any known guideline about

1. Short hint or quick fragmentary informations are anyway allowed or not.
2. If that is okay, how much information (according to word counts or number of points, etc.) would be considered as 'short hint', and from when would it be considered as answering-as-comment? Even-if in any approximate-scale.

If such à guideline does not exist, should we have one?

Comment: This really is a per-site thing. Many sites don't mind this but some may have rules about it.

Comment: What @Catija says (which, the irony, is a short hint of its own). On Mathematics SE, you literally *stumble* over hints in comments.

Comment: On Puzzling, it's illegal - they get removed if you do that.

Comment: Once upon a time I was told by an user (I can't recall which user), something like "this answer is not much confirmed, why you don't use comments instead?"